# What's the best way to get the email of the author of a referenced node

Tags: 7, tokens

I'm looking to use a combination of Mailhandler with either Rules or Notifications. When a volunteer creates a "note" (a node that references another node), I want to notify the author of the referenced node. The use case here is a volunteer helpdesk where a volunteer logs a note on a ticket, and the ticket's author receives an email.

It seems like a custom token to locate the ticket author's email would be useful in either situation. Is that the right approach? If so, are there any code samples of creating a D7 token that does something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Rules:

1. Create a new Rule that reacts on event *After saving new content*.
2. Add a condition *Content is of type* to the rule and select the *note* content type in the content types section.
3. Add an action *Fetch entity by id* to the rule.

   1. As entity type, select *Node*.
   2. In the *Identifier* section, press button *Switch to data selection* (unless you already see an input field labeled *Data selector*).
   3. From the *Data selectors* section, find the selector that references the ticket that is associated to the note. Copy that value into the *Data selector* input field.
   4. In the *Fetched entity* section, set the variable label to "Referenced ticket" and the variable name to "referenced_ticket"
   5. Save the action.
4. Add an action *Send mail* to the rule. You can now use *referenced-ticket:author:mail* as data selector for the recipient.

Comment: holy crap, i didn't realize Rules had gotten THAT awesome in D7! I'll try it out tonight and mark this as the answer after testing.

Comment: This was already possible in the Drupal 6 version of Rules. Instead of *Fetch entity by id* you would use *Load referenced node*. This would provide a token *[referenced_ticket:author-mail]*.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I guess I just never had a use case before now. Thanks again for the help!